Flutter TextSpan has incorrect <href> when ensureSemantics is used to build default tree
I have a Flutter app that builds a Semantics tree by calling SemanticsBinding.instance.ensureSemantics(); on startup.
When this is done, TextSpans with TapGestureRecognizers are being rendered in the Semantics tree with href='#' (see screenshot). When the user taps on these elements, the TapGestureRecognizer onTap method is invoked, but the app also incorrectly navigates to '#.' I cannot figure out how to change this behavior. I would rather not exclude semantics on these elements because I'd like them to be findable by automated tests. Help greatly appreciated.
Example TextSpan
Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
    children: [
       Flexible(
          child: RichText(
                 text: TextSpan(
                  style: AppTextStyle.body.copyWith(color: AppColor.gray3),
                  children: [
                      TextSpan(text: subtitle),
                      TextSpan(recognizer: TapGestureRecognizer()
                                  ..onTap = () => launch(learnMoreUrl),
                               text: 'Learn More',
                               style: AppTextStyle.body.copyWith(
                               color: Colors.blue,
                               decoration: TextDecoration.underline,
                              ),
                  ]),
       ),
       // etc

                       

The above code will launch a new tab and navigate to learnMoreUrl, then promptly navigate itself back to the home page.
Element in the Semantics Tree:


We had the same issue when we upgraded to Flutter 3.19 but now Flutter 3.24.2 seems to have fixed it.
